What is the meaning of green plus icons in component headers?
Some components have these green plus icons. Some don't.
What does it mean?


This +-icon means that that the game object you are looking at is an instance of a Prefab, but that this particular component does not come from that Prefab. The component was added to the object after it was instantiated from the prefab.
